# How to balance panel data by adding missing rows with no information?

Tags: python, pandas, panel-data

I have an unbalanced dataset, namely `unbalanced.df` that looks as follows:

| Date | ID | City | State | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 500 |
| 2019-02 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 995 |
| 2019-03 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 943 |
| 2019-01 | 10002 | Houston | TX | 4330 |
| 2019-03 | 10002 | Houston | TX | 2340 |
| 2019-01 | 10003 | Sacramento | CA | 235 |
| 2019-02 | 10003 | Sacramento | CA | 239 |
| 2019-03 | 10003 | Sacramento | CA | 233 |

As you can see, Houston does not have `2019-02` as a Date. This happens all throughout my panel data with different cities.

I want to make this panel symmetric by adding NA rows on the missing dates, such that the new panel data looks like this, `balanced.df`:

| Date | ID | City | State | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 500 |
| 2019-02 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 995 |
| 2019-03 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 943 |
| 2019-01 | 10002 | Houston | TX | 4330 |
| 2019-02 | 10002 | Houston | TX | NaN |
| 2019-03 | 10002 | Houston | TX | 2340 |
| 2019 -01 | 10003 | Sacramento | CA | 235 |
| 2019-02 | 10003 | Sacramento | CA | 239 |
| 2019-03 | 10003 | Sacramento | CA | 233 |

In this case, I have an absolute minimum date and absolute maximum date, so I want to make sure that all cities follow the same dates. How can I fill my panel with NaN rows for cities and have therefore the same number of rows for each ID, City and State?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, that offers an efficient abstraction, is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get missing rows for the combination of `Date` vs the group of `('ID', 'City', 'State')`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.complete(('ID', 'City', 'State'), 'Date')

      Date     ID         City State  Quantity
0  2019-01  10001  Los Angeles    CA     500.0
1  2019-02  10001  Los Angeles    CA     995.0
2  2019-03  10001  Los Angeles    CA     943.0
3  2019-01  10002      Houston    TX    4330.0
4  2019-02  10002      Houston    TX       NaN
5  2019-03  10002      Houston    TX    2340.0
6  2019-01  10003   Sacramento    CA     235.0
7  2019-02  10003   Sacramento    CA     239.0
8  2019-03  10003   Sacramento    CA     233.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this use multiIndexes and reindex:

```
mapp = df.set_index('ID')[['City', 'State']].drop_duplicates()
df1 = df.set_index(['Date', 'ID'])\
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Date'].unique(),
                                             df['ID'].unique()], 
                                            names=['Date', 'ID']))\
        .reset_index()
df1.assign(City=df1['ID'].map(mapp['City']), State=df1['ID'].map(mapp['State']))
```

Output:

```
      Date     ID         City State  Quantity
0  2019-01  10001  Los Angeles    CA     500.0
1  2019-01  10002      Houston    TX    4330.0
2  2019-01  10003   Sacramento    CA     235.0
3  2019-02  10001  Los Angeles    CA     995.0
4  2019-02  10002      Houston    TX       NaN
5  2019-02  10003   Sacramento    CA     239.0
6  2019-03  10001  Los Angeles    CA     943.0
7  2019-03  10002      Houston    TX    2340.0
8  2019-03  10003   Sacramento    CA     233.0
```

If you have a lot of columns, then you can use `merge` instead of `assign`:

```
df[['ID', 'City', 'State']].drop_duplicates().merge(df1[['ID', 'Quantity']], on='ID')
```

Comment: How does the code change when there is an extra column associated with ID? Would I just have to assign new columns as you did with the state? Sorry I am still learning how to code in python.

Comment: You can chain another assign and map using df.set_index('City')['Id'] again. But if you lots of other fields, then we merge back to the original dataframe.

Comment: Tried running that code and the `State` column only fills out the first line for each state, and the following ones become NA. How can I solve this problem? I edited the question for more context and tried taking the drop.duplicates() out but received an error because of the existence of duplicates.

Comment: @RafaelP See update using multiple assigns.

Comment: I ran the code and it works in creating NA rows but it only copies the ID on these rows, not the City or State. What can be the error? Tried using the assign function and it didn't pass through it seems.

Comment: @RafaelP You need to save that to another variable. `df_out = df1.assign(City=df1['ID'].map(mapp['City']), State=df1['ID'].map(mapp['State']))` then look at df_out.